# How send bson via Spring @response body

Tags: json, spring, annotations, response, bson

I am using @Responsebody String to send JSON.
part of my code is below.(I am sorry for open it all)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSomeList", method = RequestMethod.GET ,
            headers="Accept=application/json", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String getThumbList(
            @RequestParam("con_id") String con_id) throws Exception{
return json;

}
```

And actually it sends Json. But my client requests Bson type. How can I change Json to Bson without editing global format(my json is actually just string and I heard that spring can not response bson. Is that right?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) that can convert to BSON.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
          <bean class="MyBsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
     </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Unfortunaly Spring has no Bson Http Message Converter, so you have to implement your own. (Or have more luck then me while google for one).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it is nigh the only thing I can find on the web on this topic.

So here's how to do it. *Assuming you're using Jackson as your JSON library in Spring.*

1. Add a dependency to [Michel Krämer's bson4jackson library](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson)
2. Create a class like so:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import de.undercouch.bson4jackson.BsonFactory;
import de.undercouch.bson4jackson.BsonGenerator;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class MappingJackson2BsonHttpMessageConverter
    extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter
{
    public MappingJackson2BsonHttpMessageConverter(@Nonnull Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        super(bsonObjectMapper(builder), MediaType.parseMediaType("application/bson"));
    }

    @Nonnull
    private static ObjectMapper bsonObjectMapper(@Nonnull Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder om){
        BsonFactory f = new BsonFactory();
        f.configure(BsonGenerator.Feature.ENABLE_STREAMING, true);

        return om.factory(f).build();
    }
}
```

3. Add it as a `@Bean` to your configuration, or annotate it with `@Component` and make sure it's in your `@ComponentScan`'s path.

That's it. Now, if you declare your MVC endpoint with `@RequestMapping(produces = "application/bson")` (in some form or another), the output will be the BSON encoding of your ResponseEntity's body.

This works with Jackson-annotated Objects which you'd normally serialize to JSON; and all the configuration you did to the Jackson `ObjectMapper` through Spring, modules or annotations will apply.

It also works for input as well as for output.

It also works with [Feign clients](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign).
I assume it also works with Spring's `RestTemplate`.